Default QGIS style symbologies not displaying
I have been installing and uninstalling QGIS (different versions) yet they are not displaying features symbols/styles in the symbology.
I am using a HP ELITEBOOK core i7, 8 gen, Windows 11.
What might be the issue?


Try clicking on the "All" tab in the style manager. I notice you are clicked on the "Favorites" tab in the image, and if you haven't saved any favorites, it might not show anything.

I have clicked all tab, still nothing. I have exhousted all the possible activation yet no change, i think there is something i need to do within my computer coz other computers have no issue with that.

Yeah that makes me wonder if the symbols/styles are not being store properly or if the layers you are trying are somehow corrupt. Have you tried loading in different layers besides the ones you've tested? For example, try creating a new layer from scratch and see if you still cannot see the symbology.
